# Automatic labels for shortenumerate items from the shortlst package

Tags: enumerate, labels, enumitem

For usual `enumerate` environments one can easily setup automatic item labels via `\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]` for example. I am using `shortenumerate` from `shortlst` and this approach apparently isn't available to that environment. Is there any other way to include automatic labels for those items?

Comment: Since `shortlst` predates `enumitem` such an interface it unlikely to be available.

Comment: Perhaps the `inline` feature of `enumitem` is an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can define them by yourself by

```
\begin{shortenumerate}
\item This is an item
\item[\Alph] This is an item with an Alph
\item[\%] This is an item with a per cent sign
\end{shortenumerate}
```

I found this in the package documentation. I couldn't test it, because shortlst does not work in my file and I normally don't use it.

Comment: I know that I can do this, but it is annoying to do it manually especially if you change the order of items. That's why I was looking for an automated way.

Answer (score 1):

I also couldn't find `shortlst` to test, but perhaps if it is incompatible with `enumitem` it might still work with the [`enumerate`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumerate?lang=en) package? (Note that `enumerate` uses a different syntax for changing the labels.) If not, according to [this answer](http://forum.mathematex.net/latex-f6/redefinir-les-labels-de-shortenumerate-t14480.html) you can still use the old-fashioned

```
{\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}}
\begin{shortenumerate}
  \item ...
\end{shortenumerate}}
```

Of course, you'll need to change accordingly if your enumerate isn't at the `enumi` level.